# What has happened to Wikibooks?

Tags: formatting

I know this might be slightly meta/offtopic, but I have no idea where else to turn. Does anyone know what has happened to the great LaTeX guides at [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX)? For example, I was looking up something about figures and all the previously fine formatted code examples has now been wrapped (almost) unreadable; see [LaTeX/Floats, Figures and Captions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions).

Does anyone know if any changes have been done and if there is something quick one can do to change the code back into its readable state?

Comment: wow, that's quite a change. I don't know if you'll get much help here, but fingers crossed :)

Comment: Somebody tripped over a wire, changed the formatting template and now everything looks like scrambled eggs. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Template_talk:LaTeX/Usage

Comment: A lot of the information at Wikibooks is old, obsolete and in parts even completely wrong. Be careful.

Comment: @Johannes_B That's a shame, but thanks for the lookout. Any more updated example/guide library to look up instead?

Comment: [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) and other free LaTeX books by Nicola Talbot are quite good.

Comment: I've fixed it -- it looks like the behaviour of the `<source>` (now a synonym for `<syntaxhighlight>` extension has changed when used with `enclose="none"`.  The template `LaTeX/Usage` needed modifying.

Comment: @Johannes_B if you find errors please feel free to point them out -- google indexes wikibooks quite highly and so a lot of people end up there.  I've dealt with a few things but I'm no expert in what's been deprecated.

Comment: @ChrisH This needs a lot of effort and time. If i could i would write some pages from scratch. I have already made some edits and will make further ones.

Comment: @Johannes_B it does indeed; I was only suggesting flagging things as you spot them.

Comment: @ChrisH Kudos! Content errors aside, everything look normal again.

Comment: @ChrisH https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Template:LaTeX/Example&stable=0 I changed this, but it needs checking.

Comment: @ChrisH The thanks goes to you: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Template_talk:LaTeX/Example

Comment: @Johannes_B -- teamwork!